# question about asynchronous http

Tags: android

I just want to check if I understood well the way asynchronous Http request work on Android.
Suppose I make such a request and set a `ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler` to handle the response. By doing this is it possible to have the UI thread blocked waiting for the response ? The implication being that the code in the function:

```
public String handleResponse(HttpResponse response)
```

is also executed on the UI thread or is there silently spawned a thread that waits for the response and calls the handleResponse(HttpResponse response) function  when the response arrives ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By doing this is it possible to have
>   the UI thread blocked waiting for the
>   response ?

Calling `execute()` with or without a `ResponseHandler` will block that thread until the HTTP request has been processed. If you call `execute()` on the main application thread, you will block the UI. This is not a good thing -- use `AsyncTask` to `execute()` on a separate thread, then use your `onPostExecute()` implementation to update your UI with the results of the request.

Comment: Could you provide more information about "onPostExecute()"  function ?

Comment: When you implement an `AsyncTask`, you can override `onPostExecute()`. This is called on the main application thread, after the background work from `doInBackground()` is completed. Here is an example project from one of my books that shows using HttpClient with `AsyncTask`: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service/WeatherPlus/